# How to paste all values (strings) in one data column with all other headers, conditioned on the combination of value and header

Tags: r, string, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```r
library(tibble)

df_of_measures <-
  tribble(~measure, ~meter, ~cubic_ft, ~milliliter, ~mile, ~kilogram, ~pound,
        "volume", FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
        "distance", TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
        "mass", FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)

##   measure  meter cubic_ft milliliter mile  kilogram pound
##   <chr>    <lgl> <lgl>    <lgl>      <lgl> <lgl>    <lgl>
## 1 volume   FALSE TRUE     TRUE       FALSE FALSE    FALSE
## 2 distance TRUE  FALSE    FALSE      TRUE  FALSE    FALSE
## 3 mass     FALSE FALSE    FALSE      FALSE TRUE     TRUE
```

I want to take the `measure` column and cross its values with the other headers so I get a vector only for the `TRUE` combinations:

```r
[1] "volume_cubic_ft"   "volume_milliliter" "distance_meter"    "distance_mile"     "mass_kilogram"     "mass_pound"
```

*If I weren't trying to condition* such operation on whether it's `TRUE` or `FALSE`, I would have done:

```r
as.vector(outer(df_of_measures$measure, names(df_of_measures)[-1], paste, sep="_"))

##  [1] "volume_meter"        "distance_meter"      "mass_meter"          "volume_cubic_ft"     "distance_cubic_ft"   "mass_cubic_ft"      
##  [7] "volume_milliliter"   "distance_milliliter" "mass_milliliter"     "volume_mile"         "distance_mile"       "mass_mile"          
## [13] "volume_kilogram"     "distance_kilogram"   "mass_kilogram"       "volume_pound"        "distance_pound"      "mass_pound"
```

How could I get a vector with only the `TRUE` combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `base R` where use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the rows, get the `names` of the columns that have values TRUE and `paste` with the first column or first element value

```
c( apply(df_of_measures, 1, function(x) 
        paste(x[1], names(x)[-1][as.logical(x[-1])], sep="_")))
```

-output

```
#[1] "volume_cubic_ft"   "volume_milliliter" "distance_meter"  
#[4]  "distance_mile"     "mass_kilogram"     "mass_pound"
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, `filter` based on the 'value' TRUE values, and `unite` the columns `measure` and `name`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_of_measures %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -measure) %>%
    filter(value) %>%
    unite(measure, measure, name, sep="_") %>%
    pull(measure)
#[1] "volume_cubic_ft"   "volume_milliliter" "distance_meter"  
#[4] "distance_mile"     "mass_kilogram"     "mass_pound"
```

Comment: I like your first solution. Can be better `function(x) paste(x[1], names(x)[x==TRUE], sep="_")`.

Comment: @MarcosPérez `apply` converts to `matrix` and it can have only a single class.  So the logical gets converted to string.  that is the reason I used `as.logical`

Answer (score 1):

Reshaping wide to long using `reshape2::melt`,

```
r <- reshape2::melt(df_of_measures, "measure", names(df_of_measures)[-1])
Reduce(paste0, c(r[r$value, 1:2], "_")[c(1, 3, 2)])
# [1] "distance_meter"    "volume_cubic_ft"  
# [3] "volume_milliliter" "distance_mile"    
# [5] "mass_kilogram"     "mass_pound"
```

or base `reshape`.

```
r <- reshape(as.data.frame(df_of_measures), idvar="measure", 
             times=names(df_of_measures)[-1], varying=2:7, v.names="x", direction="long")
Reduce(paste0, c(r[r$x, 1:2], "_")[c(1, 3, 2)])
# [1] "distance_meter"    "volume_cubic_ft"  
# [3] "volume_milliliter" "distance_mile"    
# [5] "mass_kilogram"     "mass_pound"
```